# How to migrate the existing database to oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I need to migrate an existing application's database into oracle RDS database in Amazon Web services.

I have the dump file which is residing on an EC2 instance. The dump has not been taken by me.Also I would like to know how can I take the dump so that it can be imported successfully. The EC2 instance has an oracle regular client.

I have set up the oracle RDS instance in AWS and I am able to connect to the server.

I would like to know how can I import the database dump on RDS.

I am using this command :

```
imp rdsuser@oracledb FILE=fulldb.dmp TOUSER=rdsuser FROMUSER=SYSTEM log=test.log buffer=100000
```

Any lead is appreciated.

Also I would like to know what is the best method to import an existing database:

```
1. to take dump.
2. Or to take the clone of all files of database ( that will require the downtime in the server).
```

Answer (score 0):

Best strategy is to take dump then import it into RDS . If your DB size is too big then contact AWS guys for help .

Comment: Could you please tell me the right procedure from the scratch. I don't find the documentation useful. Please help